# How to save the cut command result in a file

Tags: bash, cut

my question is simple:

I used :

```
for file in `/path/*_aa.fasta.aln; do cut -f 1 -d "|" ${file} > ${file}.1; done`
```

Here as you can see I store the result in the `${file}.1` but how to juste do it on `${file}` directly ?

Comment: I don't think this is what you are doing. Just for fun, try taking the code you put in your question and copying it back into a script on your own machine, and see what errors you get when you run it.

Comment: And are you hoping to *edit the file in-place*?  The `cut` command doesn't do that. No shell tools do that (including `sed`, which only fakes it).

Comment: I did it, there is no error, juste that I delete all part after a "|" in each `${file}` but it creats de modification in a file called ${file}.1 but I would like instead to save the change into `${file}.1` to directly make the modification in the `${file}`.

Comment: Yes the idea is to edit the file in place, I thought it was possible.

Comment: The code you posted has [syntax error](http://tpcg.io/dzjdjC). `I did it, there is no error` no there is. You are not pasting the code you provided in the question.

Comment: As it stands in your question, you have a backquote after the `in` denoting a command substitution, but the first thing inside the backquotes is not a command. Fix your question so that you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you may get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't read and write to a file sumltanously, you need to save/buffer the output, then output (the output) to the file.

Example like (this removes/adds only one trailing empty newlines):

```
cmd file | { buf=$(cat); printf "%s\n" "$buf" } > file
```

or:

```
temp=$(mktemp)
cmd file > "$temp"
mv "$temp" file
```

or if you have [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) which does exactly that:

```
cmd file | sponge file
```

So you can:

```
for file in /path/*_aa.fasta.aln; do 
    cut -f 1 -d "|" ${file} > ${file}.1
    mv ${file}.1 ${file}
done
```

or if you have `sponge`:

```
for file in /path/*_aa.fasta.aln; do 
    cut -f 1 -d "|" "${file}" | sponge "${file}"
done
```

Note: don't use backquotes ` `. Use command substitution `$( ... )`. Backquotes are deprecated, unreadable and become more unreadable when nested.

Comment: Thank you for your help it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for file in "/path/*_aa.fasta.aln";
do 
    cut -f 1 -d "|" ${file} > ${file}.tmp; 
    mv  ${file}.tmp ${file}; 
done
```

Comment: The `"/path/*_aa.fasta.aln";` needs to be unquoted for the globulation expansion to happen.

Comment: My _globulation_ works fine in bash 4.4: `for file in "./*"; do echo $file; done;`